# AWK: print columns, sum of column, & possible missing column

Tags: bash, awk, printing

**For a little background:** I have output from the jms ems admin tool reporting connections to a JMS queue.  I currently filter out the 5th, 6th, and NF-1 columns (needed as the 7th column is not always present) and summing the NF-1 column based upon the 5th column, using this statement:

```
echo $input|awk '$4 = "+" {print $5, $(NF-1), $6}'|awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]=$3}END{for (i in a){print "           "a[i]"\t",b[i]"\t"i}}'
```

While I'm sure you know what I'm doing, I'll break down the thought process.

1. Input entering from the source and piped in
2. Check that the 4th filed is a plus sign and print the fields I want (mostly for division of labor and I can test input on Step 3
3. Sum column 2 (original NF-1) based upon column 1 (original 5th field) and print the rest

**Example input:**

```
J  553386752 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 1   10:39:47
J  553386804 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:44
J  553386815 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386851 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386895 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:41
J  553386931 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386932 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553391311 +--T  -  vm1657            ueai099    cn=ubai090,ou=domain,o=bn,udi=bai-event-mover-3_0-vm165d-prod                                                                                       1   10:39:44
J  553433995 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553433996 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553433997 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553435753 +--Q  +  vm1479            ubrm099    some-other-program-name-1_0-prod-vm1454-2014-08-12T15:31:59.541Z.vm1454                                                                             4   10:39:44
J  553435927 +--T  +  vm1479            ubrm099    ${JMS_CLIENT_ID}.admin.vm1433.2014-08-12T15:32:26.743Z                                                                                                                       1   10:39:50
```

**What I would desire for output:**

```
[sum of NF-1 based upon the uniqueness of $5 AND $7 (if it exists)]   [$6]   [$5]   [$7]
```

**which would look like:**

```
#   user     server  program (clientID)
25  utsl099  vm1868
15  usln099  vm1479
4   ubrm099  vm1479  some-other-program-name-1_0-prod-vm1454
1   ubrm099  vm1479  ${JMS_CLIENT_ID}.admin.vm1433
```

**The obstacles would be:**

1. IF $7 == $NF-3, then the intermittent field DOES exist and should be printed
2. SUM based upon the possible existence of the field AND $5

If there is a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.  I feel this is a challenge, but figured more minds to it would help, as I am not an awk expert. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a starting form to extract fields:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='3 10 6 3 18 11 148 4 8' -v OFS='|' \
        '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sub(/[ \t]*$/, "", $i) } 1' file
```

Output:

```
J|553386752|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386804|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386815|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386851|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386895|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386931|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553386932|+--Q|+|vm1868|utsl099|||
J|553391311|+--T|-|vm1657|ueai099|cn=ubai090,ou=domain,o=bn,udi=bai-event-mover-3_0-vm165d-prod|1|10:39:44
J|553433995|+--Q|+|vm1479|usln099|||
J|553433996|+--Q|+|vm1479|usln099|||
J|553433997|+--Q|+|vm1479|usln099|||
J|553435753|+--Q|+|vm1479|ubrm099|some-other-program-name-1_0-prod-vm1454-2014-08-12T15:31:59.541Z.vm1454|4|10:39:44
J|553435927|+--T|+|vm1479|ubrm099|${JMS_CLIENT_ID}.admin.vm1433.2014-08-12T15:32:26.743Z||
```

#### Update

On an input with aligned columns:

```
J  553386752 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 1   10:39:47
J  553386804 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:44
J  553386815 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386851 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386895 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:41
J  553386931 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553386932 +--Q  +  vm1868            utsl099                                                                                                                                                                                 4   10:39:47
J  553391311 +--T  -  vm1657            ueai099    cn=ubai090,ou=domain,o=bn,udi=bai-event-mover-3_0-vm165d-prod                                                                                                                1   10:39:44
J  553433995 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553433996 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553433997 +--Q  +  vm1479            usln099                                                                                                                                                                                 5   10:39:50
J  553435753 +--Q  +  vm1479            ubrm099    some-other-program-name-1_0-prod-vm1454-2014-08-12T15:31:59.541Z.vm1454                                                                                                      4   10:39:44
J  553435927 +--T  +  vm1479            ubrm099    ${JMS_CLIENT_ID}.admin.vm1433.2014-08-12T15:32:26.743Z                                                                                                                       1   10:39:50
```

This code:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='3 10 6 3 18 11 173 4 8' -v OFS='\t' \
       '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sub(/[ \t]*$/, "", $i) }
        $4 == "+" { a[$5] += $8; b[$5] = $6; c[$5] = $7 }
        END { for (i in a) { print " " a[i], b[i], i, c[i]} }' file
```

Produces

```
 20     ubrm099 vm1479  ${JMS_CLIENT_ID}.admin.vm1433.2014-08-12T15:32:26.743Z
 25     utsl099 vm1868
```

Comment: Let me try to work with fixed widths and see how that goes.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Worked using:

`|awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='3 10 6 3 18 11 173 4 8' -v OFS='|' '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sub(/[ \t]*$/, "", $i) } 1'|awk -F'|' '$4 = "+" {print $5, $8, $6, $7}'|awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]=$3;c[$1]=$4}END{for (i in a){print "           "a[i]"\t",b[i]"\t"i"\t"c[i]}}'`

Thanks!

Comment: @krmarshall87 I noticed that the last 2 columns in your line 8 and 12 are not aligned with the other last 2 columns in the other lines. Are they really like that even in your original file?

Comment: `$4 = "+"` probably should be `$4 == "+"`. And please check the simplified code.

Comment: When I started applying this to the thousands of rows based upon queues names it was revealed that the width of the columns are dynamic based upon the widest value provided, thus very variable.  Is there anyway to so something like $7 == $NF-3, print $7 ?